# Trying to duplicate lines and parse list in NPP

Tags: notepad++, boost-regex, obsidian

Given a list of profile image links in markdown with varying name lengths:

```
![[Last, First.jpg]]
![[Longerlast, Longerfirst.jpg]]
etc
```

How can I convert to the following using regex in NPP?

```
![[Last, First.jpg]]
::Last, First
![[Longerlast, Longerfirst.jpg]]
::Longerlast, Longerfirst
etc
```

I was able to isolate the first and last patterns through trial and error, but am running into a wall before a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^!\[\[(.+?)\.jpg]]\K`
- Replace with: `\n::$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
!\[\[       # literally ![[
(.+?)       # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
\.jpg]]     # literally .jpg]]
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n          # liebreak, you can use \r\n for Windows EOL
::          # ::
$1          # content of group 1 i.e. last, first
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression replace of `^(!\[\[)(.*, *)(.*)(\.jpg\]\])` with `\1\2\3\4\r\n::\2\3`.

Explanation

```
^(!\[\[)           The front part, in capture group 1
(.*, *)            The first word and the comma space, in capture group 2
(.*)               The second word, in capture group 3
(\.jpg\]\])        The trailing part, in capture group 4
```

Replacement

```
\1\2\3\4            Reassemble the input line
\r\n                Line break
::\2\3              The second line
```

Note that if you do a couple of "Replace" actions to test it plus a "Replace all" then the will be a couple of duplicated outputs. To prevent that sort of thing I would normally use a replacement such as `---\1\2\3\4\r\n::\2\3` to add a marker string to the pieces that have been processed, then do another "Replace all" (in this case of `^---` with nothing) to remove those markers.